# Track the location of mobile

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am working on building a website for mobile which will track the location of the mobile and then will do a location based search. Can anyone help with how to get the location of the mobile phone. I am using jquerymobile and php.

Comment: You dont need to find the location of mobile, make a mobile application that will send its location on periodic basis to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the HTML5 Geolocation API there are some other options that provide web based APIs.

Telefonica has made available location for developers through both a web API and an Android SDK from Bluevia https://bluevia.com/en/
AT&T has a similar API for location http://developer.att.com/developer/apiLandingPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700218
Verizon also offer a location API too http://developer.verizon.com/content/vdc/en/verizon-tools-apis/verizon_apis/network-api.html

It is also worth noting that the network operators are currently rolling out the OneAPI standard that provides a single API for developers to use across all networks (including location). This has so far been released in Canada http://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the HTML5 Geolocation API:

```js
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(locationSuccess, locationError, {timeout: 30000});

function locationSuccess(position)
{
    // this is your position as a LatLng object. use it however you need
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}

function centerOnLocationError(err)
{
    if (err.code == 1)
        alert("You must allow this website to use the Geolocation API to access your position.");
    else if (err.code == 3)
        alert("Unfortunately, your position request timed out.");
    else
        alert("Unfortunately, your position could not be determined.");
}
```